# BLE speeds with different versions of Android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need to pass files over BLE and have made a protocol using writes with no response from Android to some hardware that I have designed.

In this test, I used my phone running Lolipop and with write without response, got good results of about 3.1Kb/s. 
I then tried it on a tablet running Android 4.3 and the speed was 1.1KB/s.

I tried further tests on a range of devices and it seems that with Lolipop I get around 3KB/s and 4.3 is from 1.1 - 1.8KB/s
A Nexus 7 gave absolutely terrible results of 350B/s

Does anyone know how my results can vary so much between 4.3 and 5.0? at below 2KB/s, Android is unusable for our project which is really disappointing.

Can anyone shed any light? Can Android version make this much difference?

Thanks

Comment: Why not classic BT as it's far more appropriate for this than LE.  You need to use the right tool for the job.

Comment: Yes I absolutely agree with you, I feel like I'm really fighting against BLE here. However we need to use BLE because its extremely low cost versus classic BLE.

Comment: You may want to check the LE Connection Parameters (specifically Interval). The [default connection parameters vary by phone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24945620/excessive-l2cap-read-errors-on-linux/28388464#28388464); can you investigate your phones’ defaults or make sure your peripheral sends a L2CAP Connection Parameter Update Request? Other than that, there may be performance differences in the Bluetooth stack software on these phones.

Comment: I found that in Android the connection interval is 39ms on both 5.0 and 4.3.  In my firmware on the BLE chip I set the minimum to 11ms so maybe 39ms is the lowest Android can go. Either way it seems that connection interval is not the issue

Comment: In case someone else gets here - in latest Android versions I seemed to get about 7 - 10 KB/s because of using larger ATT_MTU size of 517 (default for newer Androids) and using unreliable writes for client->peripheral and push data through notifications for peripheral->client communications.