# Reducing connection interval from the default 30ms

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I know the default connection interval for `CoreBluetooth` is 30 ms. I've read couple of articles that claim they can reduce it `30 ms >` by changing the `min` and `max` of the interval. I didn't see any explanation of how they were changing the parameters of it? I am assuming this is all in the iOS end.

Currently I am working on a project where the iOS device is sending packets to the bluetooth le device. When I was writing without response, there were a lot of packets being dropped so I added a handshake so once the bluetooth device receives a packet the iOS sends the next packet. This is currently taking a long time to upload a file since the connection interval is `30 ms` which I am trying to reduce.

**Any suggestions would be helpful**

**td;lr** How do I change the connection interval on iOS

**Solution** So after doing research there is no public API that allows  iOS devices to request for a connection interval change request. For Android this is possible.

Comment: You can't change any of the BLE connection characteristics from the iOS side.  If data is being lost when not using `writeWithResponse` then data is probably being sent too quickly for your peripheral to process - either improve your code on the peripheral or send data less quickly from your app.

Answer (score 2):

There is no API on iOS for a *app as master* (using `CBCentralManager`) to modify the initial Connection Parameters when connecting to a peripheral.

However, the *slave* can suggest new connection parameters using a **L2CAP Connection Parameter Update Request** (see Bluetooth 4.0 specification, Volume 3, Part A, Section 4.20), which iOS will accept if they are reasonable (see [Bluetooth Accessory Design Guidelines for Apple Products](https://developer.apple.com/hardwaredrivers/BluetoothDesignGuidelines.pdf) section 3.6 “Connection Parameters”). Peripherals should do this because [different operating systems have different default connection parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24945620/excessive-l2cap-read-errors-on-linux/28388464#28388464) that might not be optimal for a particular peripheral. For example, if you rare implementing your peripheral in iOS or OSX, call [`-[CBPeripheralManager setDesiredConnectionLatency:forCentral:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheralManager_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013015-CH1-SW29). Or, if you are using the TI BLE stack to program a CC2540 or the like, call the function [L2CAP_ConnParamUpdateReq](https://github.com/lee-wei/CC2540/blob/43b9430d1adfdc7274f526b6ee34d5f10bf43fff/Components/ble/include/l2cap.h#L377).