# BlueZ modify LE CONNECT_REQ Timeout

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I'm trying to connect to a BTLE device from Linux from C++ with BlueZ.

Connecting to most devices works fine, but there is a special device which times out with 90% probability. From a standard Android smartphone the connection to this particular device works as intended.

For @Emil's advice in my other question (thanks!) I've setup a Link Layer sniffer tool for further investigation.

During the sniff period I tried connecting to the *device(Destination)* from both *device(Good)* and *device(Bad)*.

- *Device(Good)* is working perfectly - it connected
- *Device(Bad)* is not working - timed out

Now I have a Link Layer data of both device connection trials and there is one significant difference between their trials:

*Device(Good)*'s LL Data for its *CONNECT_REQ* uses **500** for Timeout value (which is 625ms) while *Device(Bad)*'s LL Data in *CONNECT_REQ* uses **42** (which is 52.5ms).

I think *Device(Destination)*'s response is normally (mostly) arriving between those two, ie after 52.5ms and below 625ms, but sometimes it arrives in less than 52.5ms, and then also BlueZ can connect to it finally.

Is there any possibility to change this Timeout property for CONNECT_REQ in BlueZ? Maybe with *setsockopt* by any chance?

Or this is something hardcoded into kernel, even for bluetooth adapters attached to USB?

Comment: This thread helps a lot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24945620/excessive-bluetooth-le-timeouts-on-linux, it contains the solution.